# JavaScript Regex find and replace multiple word with multiple word without using multiple replace function

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript

I am using Angular7 and I want to change url defined in the environment file without concatenation.

So I have a string in my component like this.

```
"upload/document/:orgId/products/:productId"
```

I want to replace it with 2 ids using regex-only so I can get output like this. I do not want to use multiple replace calls.

```
 "/upload/document/101/products/99101"
```

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: `const replaced = "upload/document/:orgId/products/:productId".replace(":orgId", 101).replace(":productId", 99101);`

Comment: Thanks for quick response, but I want to do it in regex  somiting like     str.replace(re, "$2, $1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hard-hit and trials, this can be achieved. although it is not as I want in a single call, it is performing all the required stuff.

```
let baseUrl= "upload/document/:orgId/products/:productId";
let mapper = {
               ':orgId': 101, 
               ':productId': 99101 
             };
let newUrl = baseUrl.replace(
                 /:orgId|:productId/gi, 
                 matched => mapper[matched]
             ) ;
console.log(newUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var template = "upload/document/:orgId/products/:productId";

var result = template.replace(/:orgId\b/, '101').replace(/:productId\b/, '99101');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, but I want to do it in regex something like           str.replace(re, "$2, $1")

Comment: That's regex. `/:orgId\b/` and `/:productId\b/` are exemples of regex. If you are talking about `$1`, `$2` etc, these are replacements for contents in capture groups that must show up in the resulting string. Your problem, however, does not require capturing groups. You can use them, but then you would end up with a more complex solution just for the sake of using a specific tool. Do you must use capturing groups? (Like, is this a homework or something?)